# loopback.io: Not In query

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to do a not in query in loopback.io. But couldn't find any feature related to that. Here is what I have tried:

```
Product.find({
        where: {
            name: {
                like: '%' + searchTerm + '%'
            },
            id: {
                neq: [1,2,3]
            }
        },
        limit: 15
    }, function(err, searchResults) {...}
```

And in fact the query generated is:

```
'SELECT `id`,`name`,`ref` FROM `Product` WHERE `name` LIKE \'%iPh%\' AND `id`!=1, 2, 3 ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 15' }
```

I know we can check

```
field in (n1,n2,...)
```

using https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter#Wherefilter-inq. But I can't get the 'not in' case.

Anybody has come across this scenario before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were using `neq` which in indeed used for *not equals* as provided by you.
To use *Not In operator*, we must use `nin`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Where+filter) again, there is a table with **operators with their description**

```
Product.find({
    where: {
        name: {
            like: '%' + searchTerm + '%'
        },
        id: {
            nin: [1,2,3]
        }
    },
    limit: 15
}, function(err, searchResults) {...}
```

Comment: silly me.. didn't notice the nin operator. Thanks @Vishal